# Vendor Functionality

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-vendor

Had a quick question in regards to potential solutions for this defined functionality: I know there are a few solutions that somewhat work, unirgy, marketplace multi vendor module.

Functionality: is based on creating subset vendors from the admin portal (only to allow the backend connection of each vendors products). There is no need for vendors to have their own portal to list products, as the admin will be taking care of that.

1) `Admin section allows creation of vendor`

2) `Admin creates and assigns product to vendor`

3) Product is listed on front end as magento normally would and doesn't show any vendors names just product information.

4) Customer can purchase product and check out as magento normally would.

5) Admin can pay vendor percentage of checkout via Paypal Adaptive.

So instead of it being admin->products it would be:

Admin->Add/Use Vendor

Admin->Add/Modify Products for that vendor

Admin->Pay Vendor->Paypal Adaptive

I'm wondering if the two solutions I listed above would be a good fit or if/ they are too robust/lacking for this.

Answer (score 2):

we are the creator of webkul  marketplace multi vendor module  ( https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html )

- as in our extension all the vendors are customers initially and they turned to vendor when they have applied for that with a special flag of vendor so obviously store owner will be able to create vendor from admin
- extension does support this feature as well 
  [image]
- After the approval or auto approval of the product  all the product added by vendor / seller , will be the part of global catalog , that means vendor product will work as it is as magento product .
- After the approval or auto approval of the product  all the product added by vendor / seller will be the part of global catalog of magento so payment will work as it is as normal magento does . In this case marketplace module will support any payment method as all the payment will go to admin account and admin will manage the payment for sellers manually .
- ​Marketplace and Paypal adaptive module process

**Admin process**

- Admin need to register with paypal site for the application approval as described in the screenshot as well as in the doc right below even you can search in the blog with following heading "How to Set up Application for Paypal Adaptive Payment"

http://webkul.com/blog/magento-marketplace-paypal-adaptive-payment/

[image]

after the approval of the application from the paypal side , admin need to enter those information in the back -end of the store as described in the user guide above also i am attaching the screen-shot here as well

[image]

**Commission Explanation** 
​
​Commission will be deducted during the checkout as it will calculated with all the product in the cart and will be sent to admin during checkout.

​
**​Seller / vendor Process**

- As you know in marketplace module whenever a seller / vendor register he / she needs to provide their "payment details " as well so after the paypal adaptive module installation they need to enter their paypal id as per the screenshot

[image]

so now lets see there are three vendors v1 v2 and v3 and their respective product are p1 p2 p3 as they are distinct vendor in this case they all need to have their paypal id associated with their account .

so when buyer will make the payment , then adaptive payment will split those payment among the seller using those paypal id of every seller . As described in the doc above also attaching the screenshot 
[image]

​I hope i have clear all your doubts still have any issue please comment

**PS - we are not self promoting our plugin or product , as user asked the questions specifically about our product that why i have added extension link with images and screenshot**

Comment: No. OP didn't ask about your extension. So this is clearly self-promoting your own product!

Comment: @webkul you should not promote your product on stackoverflow, until the question is about your product.